# Dependent changelist in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I made some changes. This changes are still to be reviewed. I would to start work on another changelist which uses changes from the first one. Is it possible to do it in Perforce?

EDIT: I would like to not clutter my new changelist with files from the first, because it will make hard to discern which files have changes from which changelist. And if the first changelist has a lot of files, then handling of the second/dependent one would be a pretty nasty business.

Answer (score 2):

Shelve the changelist under review (assuming you haven't already), then move your local files to another pending changelist and continue working on them.

You will eventually need to "resolve" vs your own changes (once they're submitted), which is similar to rebasing in git; since the same changes are in both files this should be very straightforward.